# Anyone else seeing google chrome connect to 34.104.35.123 on startup?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, http

I have only noticed this over the past few days, on Mac, using the latest version of chrome, although I am unsure how long it has been happening. The actual hostname is 123.35.104.34.bc.googleusercontent.com, however it seems to have been [reported over the last year](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/34.104.35.123?page=1#report). Moreover, it's done over http, not https, which is odd as I have an extension that forces https. I've checked the PID, it's definitely chrome.

I can't fine a reason why this happens on a new, blank tab, as I have checked in the developer tools, and googleusercontent isn't a source. Moreover, I haven't changed anything in the browser, nor do I have any strange extensions installed. Is anyone else seeing this as well, or has an explanation?

Edit: Usually this only happens the first time it's launched after my mac has been powered off and on again.

Edit: Ok so both https everywhere and the browser itself are set to block http. Yet the connection still persists. To clarify again, this happens on a blank tab with nothing loaded in it.

Edit 2: It may be related to [this](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/what-are-these-suspicious-google-gvt1com-urls/), which seems to be chrome using http to get updates on startup, instead of https, and [this](https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/ip/34.104.35.123) sees to indicate that the actual domain is meant to be a gvt1 domain? Again, anyone else seeing something similar?

Comment: Just get a decent ad blocker. AdGuard or AdBlock… and stop using Chrome - the browser made by the company whose entire business model is to sell advertising to people who are greatly interested in your browsing habits. Instead try one by a company whose entire business model is to sell you next year's new Mac… & even include a tracker-prevention mechanism in it, by default. Microsoft want to sell you Windows; Apple want to sell you Macs/iDevices; Google want to sell *other people* your habits.

Comment: googleusercontent.com is owned and controlled by Google so it's not malicious, but it might be an unwanted, huge difference. "which is odd as I have an extension that forces HTTPS." - That addon only works on hosts which support https.

Comment: [IP `123.35.104.34`](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/?ip=123.35.104.34) seems to belong to domain `samsung.com`. Do you have any Samsung devices or software installed?

Comment: @Tetsujin I have uBlock Origin and uMatrix. This happens on a new tab page where nothing else is loaded. That doesn't even attempt to answer my question.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, this is true, but I have read of malicious actors using googleusercontent to host malicious content, and that still doesn't explain how it's even happening.

Comment: @harrymc you have the ip address round the wrong way. The title lists the correct one, the DNS hostname reverses it for whatever reason.

Comment: I wasn't attempting to answer your question - hence using the comment space - I was attempting to explain why you should not use a browser made by a company who only wants to sell your data to other people.

Comment: @Tetsujin Google doesn't sell your data and never has. They build ad profiles, companies tell them who they want to target and Google decides who to target using said profiles. You cannot buy a users PID  from Google. That is a fact. Besides, some of the things FF has done over the past few years, like installing that extension to promote Mr Robot and collecting user data even when the browser is off are questionable.

Comment: OK, believe what you wish. Search for a product, then see how many ads for the same thing pop up in the next week. [I can't test that any more, because I haven't seen an advert in years, but many others complain about it, frequently] Their entire business model is based on selling your habits to others, no matter how you couch it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah... that's how gathering ad data for profiles works. You've proven my point. You search for something using Google, it becomes entwined with the ads you receive. Google decides to show you those ads. Did you think it was the companies that owned the ads deciding to do that?

Comment: Why would I think that? Anyway, you asked why a Google app was contacting Google… I think you've answered that yourself, maybe without even meaning to. I was merely recommending to not trust Google as far as you can spit them. I'm done now.

Comment: @Ramhound also, I have https everywhere set to block any sites not using https. Am I to assume ito only works for sites I am currently visiting, and then doesn't block all http requests made by the browser itself?

Comment: @GaussStrife - that extension doesn’t block cross domain traffic

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't? I though the whole point of it was that your browser couldn't make any non-https requests period. This one is literally the only one I've seen. Shouldn't I at least be able to see the sources of said domain when I use the developer tools? This is a new tab, and literally nothing else is loaded.